# How to use subpattern match in pattern of regexp_replace

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

I'm trying to replace a pattern in a string in Snowflake using `regexp_replace` on comma literal.

If the string is `sample,sample`, the result should be `sample`.

If the string is `sample,random`, the result should be `sample,random`

I'm using `regexp_replace("sample,sample", '([^,]+),\1)' , '\\1' )` for this. The same query works in Oracle since `"\1"` in pattern matches the first subexpression found within ( ) before encountering end of line.

How can I achieve the same result in Snowflake?